# Trouble with 'System services not available to Activities before onCreate()'

Tags: java, android

I'm having some trouble and could with some help. I've got a MapsActivity and a LocationHelper class but when loading the MapsActivity I get presented with the errors listed below.

MapsActivity -

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 2;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private LocationHelper locationHelper;
private LatLng location;
private boolean onCreateFinished = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    onCreateFinished = true;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    //instantiates LocationHelper for use in this activity
    locationHelper = new LocationHelper(this);
    //runs startConnection from LocationHelper class
    locationHelper.startConnection();

    //starts map
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}

//sets map markers
public void setMapMarkers(){
    //runs checkLocation from LocationHelper class
    locationHelper.checkLocation();
    location = new LatLng(locationHelper.mLatitude, locationHelper.mLongitude);

    LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Your Location"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLocation));
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    locationHelper.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(onCreateFinished == true){
        setMapMarkers();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate not finished..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    locationHelper.mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    //LocationManager.removeUpdates();
    super.onStop();
}
```

LocationHelper class -

```
public class LocationHelper extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

//private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
//private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 2;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationManager mLocationManager;
//private Location mLastLocation;
private LocationListener mLocationListener;
public double mLatitude;
public double mLongitude;
private Context context;


//constructor
public LocationHelper(Context context) {
    //saves the context received from activity that instantiates LocationHelper into a local variable
    this.context = context;
}

public void startConnection() {
    // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
}

public void checkLocation(){
    //gets system service from LocationManager
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //checks permissions
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        return;
    }

    mLocationListener = new LocationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            //checks if GPS is enabled
            if(mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                if(mLocationListener != null){
                    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        return;
                    }
                    if (mLocationManager != null) {
                        location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if(location != null){
                            mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                            mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS - " + String.valueOf(mLatitude) + "," + String.valueOf(mLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //checks if internet is enabled
            else if(mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
                if(mLocationManager != null){
                    location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if(location != null){
                        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NETWORK - " + String.valueOf(mLatitude) + "," + String.valueOf(mLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            }
            //method for setting location request parameters
            setLocationRequest();
        }



        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };

}


@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public void setLocationRequest(){
    //sets locationrequest parameters
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
}

public double getLatitudeForNote() {
    return mLatitude;
}

public double getLongitudeForNote(){
    return mLongitude;
}
```

}

Error -

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.a8460p.locationotes, PID: 1715
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.a8460p.locationotes/com.example.a8460p.locationotes.MapsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3160)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3191)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2529)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
                  at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:5300)
                  at com.example.a8460p.locationotes.LocationHelper.checkLocation(LocationHelper.java:66)
                  at com.example.a8460p.locationotes.MapsActivity.setMapMarkers(MapsActivity.java:71)
                  at com.example.a8460p.locationotes.MapsActivity.onResume(MapsActivity.java:88)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1259)
                  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6361)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3149)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3191) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2529) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Delete `extends Activity` from `LocationHelper`. This is not an activity.

Step #2: Use the `context` for your call to `getSystemService()` inside of `LocationHelper`.

Step #3: Decide whether you are going to use Android's `LocationManager` *or* `LocationRequest` from the Play Services SDK, and get rid of all the code associated with the one that you are not going to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your LocationHelper instance after onCreate completed. You can move related code into onMapReady() method.